# Install griddb c client on windows

Tags: griddb

I got stucked on build the files with Cmake, it returns error and the error log says

The system is: Windows - 10.0.19042 - AMD64

does not quite understand the process with visio studio 2017
what do i need install to get a x64 project on visio studio